# join is the heart of the monad because it encompasses everything a monad can do that a functor cannot. Is this true?

Tags: functional-programming, category-theory

There is a controversy about Monad implementation in S.O .

The original question is,

[What's so special about Monads in Kleisli category?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53109889/whats-so-special-about-monads-in-kleisli-category#)

> Is there any counterexample that Functors cannot do what Monads can do *except the robustness of functional composition by flattening the nested structure*?
>
> What's so special about Monads in Kleisli category? It seems like it's fairly possible to implement Monads with a little expansion to avoid the nested structure of Functor and without the monadic functions `a -> m b` that is the entity in Kleisli category.

An answer is

> "Avoiding the nested type" is not, in fact, the purpose of join, it's just a neat side-effect. The way you put it makes it sound like join just strips the outer type, but the monad's value is unchanged.
>
> You can think of a functor as basically a container. There's an arbitrary inner type, and around it an outer structure that allows some variance, some extra values to "decorate" your inner value. fmap allows you to work on the things inside the container, the way you would work on them normally. This is basically the limit of what you can do with a functor.
>
> A monad is a functor with a special power: where fmap allows you to work on an inner value, bind allows you to combine outer values in a consistent way. This is much more powerful than a simple functor.
>
> join is the heart of the monad because it encompasses everything a monad can do that a functor cannot. Since join and >>= are isomorphic and you can define each in terms of the other, defining >>= without join still provides the same degree of freedom (you could say that defining >>= indirectly defines join, and vice versa). You get the same thing either way, except that >>= is more convenient and join is more "pure". So it is really a boring question to compare the two. – DarthFennec

The objection by the questioner is,

> I believe "Avoiding the nested type" is not just a neat side-effect, but a definition of "join" of Monad in category theory,

[the multiplication natural transformation μ:T∘T⇒T of the monad provides for each object X a morphism μX:T(T(X))→T(X)](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monad+%28in+computer+science%29)

> and that's exactly what my code does.
>
> I know many people implement monads in Haskell in this manner, but the fact is, there is Maybe functor in Haskell, that does not has join, or there is Free monad that join is embedded from the first place into the defined structure. They are objects that users define Functors to do things.
>
> Therefore, ... [your] observation does not fit the fact of the existence of Maybe functor and Free monad.

Which opinion is correct?

PS. Additional comment from DarthFennec (who answers) as below:

---

`Free` is weird, in that it's one of the few monads that *doesn't actually do anything*.

`Free` can be used to turn any functor into a monad, which allows you to use `do` notation and other conveniences. However, the conceit of `Free` is that `join` does not combine your actions the way other monads do, instead it keeps them separate, inserting them into a list-like structure; the idea being that this structure is later processed and the actions are combined by *separate code*. An equivalent approach would be to move that processing code into `join` itself, but that would turn the functor into a monad and there would be no point in using `Free`. So the only reason `Free` works is because it delegates the actual "doing things" part of the monad elsewhere; its `join` opts to defer action to code running outside the monad. This is like a `+` operator that, instead of adding the numbers, returns an abstract syntax tree; one could then process that tree later in whatever way is needed.

> These observation does not fit the fact of the existence of Maybe functor and Free monad.

You are incorrect. As explained, `Maybe` and `Free` fit perfectly into my previous observations:

- The `Maybe` functor simply does not have the same expressiveness as the `Maybe` monad.
- The `Free` monad transforms functors into monads in the only way it possibly can: by not implementing a monadic behavior, and instead simply deferring it to some assumed processing code.

---

First of all the word he uses "`Free` is weird" or "the conceit of `Free`" unduly disparaging the Free monad, and this words does not justify what he  insists obviously.

> An equivalent approach would be to move that processing code into `join` itself, but that would turn the functor into a monad and there would be no point in using `Free`.

My question would be if "join is the heart of the monad", how come the " processing code" has been moved away from the heart =`join` and move-back into `join` again? That is the weird.

Free is one of the generalization to abstract the "processing code" of Monad. Monad structure including `join` that satisfies the monad laws are pre-defined without the "processing code" that would be functor/ or function if it's Operational monad.

> So the only reason `Free` works is because it delegates the actual "doing things" part of the monad elsewhere; its `join` opts to defer action to code running outside the monad.

In either way, again, "doing things" does not have to locate in `join`. If someone strongly insists "join is the heart of the monad", maybe it's ok to do so. However, as Free-monad, it's totally reasonable a user let `join`  be pre-defined in a generalized structure of Monad as a functionality of  flattening the structure, or other monads also does not have to move "doing things" to `join` because it's not  the heart of the monad anyway.

Comment: What's your _question_? This mostly seems to be a discussion/argument copy-pasted from somewhere else on Stack Exchange.

Comment: I would second @DavidRicherby. "Which opinion is correct?" sounds like asking for more opinions. (Disclaimer, I cannot say I am familiar with category-theory and  functional-programming)

Comment: This is a site for technical questions, not for debate or discussion.  As such, we require you to articulate a specific technical question that you want an answer to.  Subjective questions or questions calling for opinion or discussion are off-topic here.  "Which opinion is correct?" does not seem like a suitable question.   And "the heart of" sounds like a matter of opinion.  Do you have a specific technical question, that has an objectively correct answer?  I encourage you to reflect on the discussion, see if you can find what are the facts that you want to learn, and ask about that.

Comment: You'll probably need to pare the question down, too.  That's a massive wall of text.  Finally, a question here is not the place to tell others that they are incorrect or respond to quotes or statements from others.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but since it's my answer you're wondering about, I'll do my best to clarify my meaning.<sup>1</sup>

> join is the heart of the monad because it encompasses everything a monad can do that a functor cannot. Is this true?

Let's find out!

We can define a functor<sup>2</sup> like so:

```
class Functor' f where
    pure' :: a -> f a
    fmap' :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
    ap'   :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

We can define a monad in the following way:

```
class Monad' m where
    pure' :: a -> m a
    fmap' :: (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
    ap'   :: m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
    join' :: m (m a) -> m a
```

As you can see, these are the same except for the added `join'` on the `Monad'` class. Since without this `join'` the `Monad'` is indistinguishable from the `Functor'`, I think it's safe to say that `join'` embodies everything in `Monad'` that is not in `Functor'`.

This can also be seen in the way the Haskell Prelude defines `Monad`:

```
class Applicative m => Monad m where
    (>>=)  :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b

    (>>)   :: m a -> m b -> m b
    m >> k = m >>= (\_ -> k)

    return :: a -> m a
    return = pure
```

From this we can see the following:

- Any `Monad m` must also be an `Applicative m`, meaning that all `Monad`s are also `Functor`s.
- `>>` is simply a convenience method, and is defined in terms of `>>=`.
- `return` is just another name for the applicative `pure`.
- The only remaining method defined by `Monad` is `>>=`. Therefore, `>>=` is the one thing `Monad` has that `Applicative` doesn't have.

However, we can define `>>=` in the following way:

```
(>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
m >>= f = join (fmap f m)
```

`fmap` is part of `Functor`, so `join` is the only remaining thing that's unique to `Monad`. This is why I described `join` as "the heart of the monad".

> In either way, again, "doing things" does not have to locate in `join`. If someone strongly insists "join is the heart of the monad", maybe it's ok to do so. However, as Free-monad, it's totally reasonable a user let `join` be pre-defined in a generalized structure of Monad as a functionality of flattening the structure, or other monads also does not have to move "doing things" to `join` because it's not the heart of the monad anyway.

I'm not sure I understand what you mean. `join` is the place in a `Monad` where the actual "doing" is defined; this is where the *purpose* of the `Monad` is encoded. The *purpose* of `Free` is to displace the "actual" processing logic for the user to deal with somewhere else. I suppose you could say that `Free` is a way to transform a `Monad` problem into a data processing problem, in that `join` creates a data structure that can later be processed. This is unusual because most `Monad`s encode destructive processing into `join`, but this doesn't have to be the case. But the fact that the "heart" of `Free` is the displacement of the business logic does not mean `join` doesn't represent the "heart" of a `Monad`.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>Note that I don't have a category theory background, so I'm going to be working in the context of Haskell. I assume that's okay, since this question is tagged as `[functional-programming]`.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup>This is actually an "applicative functor", which defines a couple of extra methods. I believe this is appropriate, as the questioner's original question defined a functor with `fmap` and `unit`, the latter being another name for the applicative `pure`.</sub>

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85418/discussion-on-answer-by-darthfennec-join-is-the-heart-of-the-monad-because-it-en).